# Скрипт автоматической генерации квитанции

Tags: html, excel

Допустим есть таблица Excel c Полями "Фамилия" "Номер" "Счет" "ИТОГО" в которой N записей.
Мне необходимо сформировать N html-документов, в которые в качествe параметров должны подставляться значения из полей таблицы.
Проще говоря нужно сформировать HTML-квитанции. 
Какими средствами это можно сделать?
Возможно есть готовые решения?

Comment: Вначале Вам нужно определиться с языком разработки. *Какими средствами это можно сделать?* например на [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описанный функционал реализуется с помощью двух листов MS Excel и макрос VBA следующим образом:
**а.** 1-ый лист содержит строки с информацией о Фамилиях, Номерах, Счетах, ИТОГО и т.д.;
**б.** 2-ой лист содержит отчетную форму содержащую ссылки на строку из 1-го листа;
**в.** макрос, который сканирует данные 1-го листа и подставляет во 2-ой лист и сохраняет как Html.

1-ый лист (данные)
[image: 1-ый лист (данные)]

2-ой лист (отчетная форма)
[image: 2-ой лист (отчетная форма)]

Код макроса

```
Sub MovingАlongTheLines()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim strDtSet As String
    Dim strRpFrm As String
    Dim strFile As String

    'блокируем вывод предупреждения при сохранении Html о персональных данных
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'список используемых листов
    'лист с исходными данными
    strDtSet = "1-ИсхДн"

    'лист с отчетной формой
    strRpFrm = "2-Отч"

    'определяем количество строк на листе strDtSet
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'сканиурем строки листа strDtSet
    For i = 2 To LastRow

        'в лист strRpFrm подставляем значения из листа strDtSet
        'Фамилие определяем
        Worksheets(strRpFrm).Cells(3, 2) = Cells(i, 1)
        'Номер счета
        Worksheets(strRpFrm).Cells(5, 2) = Cells(i, 3)
        'ИТОГО
        Worksheets(strRpFrm).Cells(7, 2) = Cells(i, 4)

        'определяем имя файла для сохранения в формате Html
        strFile = Format(Now(), "yyyy mm dd\_hh-mm") _
                & " " _
                & Cells(i, 1) _
                & ".html"
        strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile
        'сохраняем файл
        Worksheets(strRpFrm).SaveAs Filename:=strFile, FileFormat:=xlHtml
    Next i
    'закрываем все книги
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Запускаем макрос **MovingАlongTheLines** получаем результат.